# How do I select a good android:sharedUserId?

Tags: android, release

Common wisdom seems to be that one should set the sharedUserId attribute immediately when starting development of a new app. See the checklist at ["To Do" list before publishing android app to market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119633/to-do-list-before-publishing-android-app-to-market)

Even after extensive googling, I have not found any directions or examples *how* to select a sharedUserId, just about the only thing I can find is that it should be a string. So, the question is:

- should the id globally unique?
- is there a size limitation to the sharedUserId string?
- might the "package" value be a good sharedUserId ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Common wisdom seems to be that one should set the sharedUserId attribute immediately when starting development of a new app.

No, common wisdom is that you should not use `android:sharedUserId` at all. Just because there was a zero-upvote (and now one-downvote) answer on a question does not make it "common wisdom".

`android:sharedUserId` is designed for firmware apps. Whatever you are trying to do with `android:sharedUserId` can be more safely handled via IPC and `signature`-level permissions.

> should the id globally unique?

You should not use `android:sharedUserId`. If you do, it needs to be unique within the set of apps that you publish under the same production signing key.

> is there a size limitation to the sharedUserId string?

You should not use `android:sharedUserId`. If you do, since it only needs to be unique within your apps, keep it reasonably sized. I imagine that there is some upper limit that will crash the compiler or something.

> might the "package" value be a good sharedUserId ?

You should not use `android:sharedUserId`. If you do, the point is to use the value across multiple apps, and therefore there will be multiple package names.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to mis-remember an article about sharedUserId's... Not having to choose something makes the decision much simpler :-)

Comment: There's no way to add a sharedUserId later once you released an app without it. IMHO using a sharedUserId does no harm. So what is the point in not using it?

Comment: @CommonsWare could you point to other method to access other app data (instead of usage `sharedUserId`)?

Comment: @barmaley: Use any IPC option: `ContentProvider`, broadcast `Intent`s, remote services, etc.