# Releasing Mobile App and Testing App Store Features

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mobile-application

I'm working on my first mobile app and am confused on how to approach the first release. I've read up on TestFlight and beta testing but am still confused about a few things.

- Seems like in-app purchases and asking to rate the app on the store aren't possible without registering the app in the app store. One wouldn't want to release the app before testing such features.
- App stores tend to highlight new and featured apps. One wouldn't want the App store to consider an app for being featured until it's ready. Wondering if it's possible to release the app privately and make it public after successful testing.

I'm sure these questions have been asked before and there are solutions to these problems. I couldn't find much information on this subject and would really appreciate some input from people who've dealt with similar issues.

Thank you!

Comment: You have the option to release an app in beta mode to the Play Store for testing purposes. Mention what is your target market.

Comment: [a quick read-out before you release](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8165788/3682535)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. It is a health and fitness app for the global audience. Wondering if TestFlight is the equivalent for beta release in Play Store.

Comment: The Apple App Store does not allow beta apps. You can use TestFlight to distribute your apps for beta testing, but this is done by sending an email to your testers who download the app through the TestFlight App.  You can test in-app-purchase on iOS in a test app using "sandbox" users that you create in iTunes connect.. The purchase is not charged. Rating an app on iOS simply launches the App Store, so you can test this even though your app won't be found (you can get the app URL in iTunesConnect even before your app is released)

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul. You clarified all my concerns.