# Play Store Important steps before release?

Tags: android, google-play-services, release

I will be releasing my first Android App on Google PlayStore in the next few days.

I programmed my app with Android Studio and Socket.IO.

Are there any important steps I have to take in Android Studio before I can release the app?
Is there a way to easily encrypt the app (apk.) code, is that necessary?

I would be happy if you could give me some tips I should pay attention to.

Thanks

Comment: Try following this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165788/5995040) and this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist) for launch checklist. Also try using Proguard to optimize, shrink and obfuscate your code.

Comment: Oh thanks for the links

Answer (score 0):

The things that I need to remember when release an app is

Module Settings -> Flavours -> version number and version name

Make sure to build APK as release with V1 and V2 selected

We also incorporate Fabric IO’s Crashylitics into our app to monitor use age and keep crash logs over different devices and versions